# Rstudio - can't view full output of "decompose"

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a large dataset and have run the decompose function on it.  However, when I try to view the decompose output, the row limitation means that most of the output is cut out (and the output displays from the bottom up).  I try to scroll up, but am barred from doing so all the way.

I don't think I can use the "view" function, since this isn't a dataset as such.

```
st<-decompose(ts(ChilledV2[1:900,1],start=start(ChilledV2),frequency=365))
st
```

How can I view the whole output?

Answer (score 1):

The output of `decompose` is simply a list that can be subset and printed like any list.  I would recommend looking at the individual pieces separately.  Here is an example from `?decompose`

```
m <- decompose(co2)
```

Here, we can see that it is simply a `list`

```
str(m)
# List of 6
#$ x       : Time-Series [1:468] from 1959 to 1998: 315 316 316 318 318 ...
#$ seasonal: Time-Series [1:468] from 1959 to 1998: -0.0536 0.6106 1.3756 2.5168 3.0003 ...
#$ trend   : Time-Series [1:468] from 1959 to 1998: NA NA NA NA NA ...
#$ random  : Time-Series [1:468] from 1959 to 1998: NA NA NA NA NA ...
#$ figure  : num [1:12] -0.0536 0.6106 1.3756 2.5168 3.0003 ...
#$ type    : chr "additive"
#- attr(*, "class")= chr "decomposed.ts"
```

Thus, you can access and slice and dice just like any other list.  Here are a few examples.

```
head(m$x)
head(m$seasonal)
head(m$figure)
head(m$trend)
head(m$random)
head(m$type)
```